# Search and Replace if read-host prompt variable is found

Tags: windows, powershell, search, replace

I am trying to create a script that basically searches for a string then replaces it with another string.  Both strings would be stored as variables and are created as the script is run by using 'Read-Host -Prompt'.  My issue is towards the bottom of the script; I want the script to look for the EXACT string input by the user, '-match' seems to do a wildcard search.  Also, inside my if statement the `Write-Host` works fine when the user input is found, but when I try to add `-replace` code under that it reports there is a nullValue.

Here is my code:

```
# Copy device.txt, append today's date, move to backup folder
$sourcePath = 'C:\path\to\source\file\file.txt'
$destPath = 'C:\path\to\source\file\Backup\file_' + (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd)+'.txt'
Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath -Destination $destPath
Write-Host 'File has been copied to backup folder'

#Ask for user input on old ID vs new ID
$oldDeviceId = Read-Host -Prompt "What is the old device ID you're replacing?"
$newDeviceId = Read-Host -Prompt "What is the new device ID?"

#Check for a match on $oldDeviceId
$sourceFile = (Get-Content 'C:\path\to\source\file\file.txt')
$sfContainsOdi = $sourceFile | ForEach-Object {$_ -match $oldDeviceId}

#If $oldDeviceId is found, replace with $newDeviceId
if ($sfContainsOdi -contains $true) {
    Write-Host "Found $oldDeviceId"
    $replaceString = $replaceString -replace ($oldDeviceId, $newDeviceId)
} else {
    Write-Host "Could not find $oldDeviceId, please make sure you've input the correct device ID"
}
```

I'm unsure of how to add `-replace` into my `if` statement.

Edit:
When I ran @Ansgar Wiechers suggestion, there was no replacement occurring. Here is a sample of my file contents:

```
QWER147,/qwer=nmsdf/asdf=A1
ASDF258,/qwer=jkl /asdf=A1
ZXCV369,/qwer=yuio /asdf=A1
```

Sometimes the ID in the first column needs to be changed.  For example what I am trying to change/replace is 'QWER147' from the list above with a new ID like 'QWER159'.

Comment: When I ran my sample code on your sample data it worked just fine. Please show the output of `$oldDeviceId, $newDeviceId | % {"-${_}-"}`.

Comment: I think I see the issue.  The output of $replaceString does show that there is replacement in the console.  But when I open the file I do not see the change saved inside it.  Do you know what would make the file save the replacement/change? @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, yes, that's why I asked "Do you know what would make the file save the replacement/change?" EDIT: I guess I could output it to another file, and then delete the current file...

Answer (score 0):

The `-match` operator (as well as the `-replace` operator) does *regular expression* matches, not wildcard matches. Also, you don't define `$replaceString` anywhere before you use it in this statement:

```
$replaceString = $replaceString -replace ($oldDeviceId, $newDeviceId)
```

Since you seem to want to work with plain string operations I'd recommend using the corresponding string methods instead of PowerShell operators.

```
$sourceFile    = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\source\file.txt'
$sfContainsOdi = $sourceFile | Where-Object { $_.Contains($oldDeviceId) }

if ($sfContainsOdi) {
    Write-Host "Found $oldDeviceId"
    $replaceString = $sourceFile.Replace($oldDeviceId, $newDeviceId)
} else {
    Write-Host "Could not find $oldDeviceId, please make sure you've input the correct device ID"
}
```

You can use `$sfContains0di` directly as the condition when you filtered the content of the file via `Where-Object`, because PowerShell will evaluate an empty value to `$false` and a non-empty value to `$true` (there are [some caveats](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/), but they most likely won't apply in your case).

Comment: Thanks for the tips Ansgar.  However, when I tried using what you suggested - I do not see any string replacement occurring.

Comment: `Write-Output $replaceString`?

Comment: Write-Output $replaceString - saves the entire file contents into the variable.

Comment: Umm... no, it doesn't. It displays the content of the variable `$replaceString`. Put the statement after the replace operation.

Comment: I did put the statement after the replace operation:

if ($sfContainsOdi)  
{  
    Write-Host "Found $oldDeviceId"  
    $replaceString = $sourceFile.Replace($oldDeviceId, $newDeviceId)  
    Write-Output $replaceString  
} else {  
    Write-Host "Could not find $oldDeviceId, please make sure you've input the correct device ID"  
} 

When I run the script the entire contents of the file are written to the console.

Comment: Of course they are. So you can check if text was or wasn't replaced. If nothing was replaced in that output please edit your question and show a text sample as well as sample input what in that text you want replaced, and with what.